# Pandas Multiindex: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have a program where I have a large pandas dataframe of pairwise interactions (in rows) that I do random walks through. The list of options for each successive step is narrowed down from the entire dataframe by specific values in two columns, so basically,

```
df_options = df[(df.A == x) & (df.B == y)]
```

I had the thing working using syntax like above, but it seemed like it would be a great idea in terms of speed (which was limiting) to index df by A, B like so:

```
df.sort(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.rename('idx')
df = df.set_index(['A', 'B'], drop=False, append=True, verify_integrity=True)
```

(note I'm keeping the original index as 'idx' because that was how I was recording the random walks and accessing specific rows)
So then I replaced the original df_options code with, firstly,
`df.xs((x, y), level=('A', 'B'))`
and after having problems with that,
`df.loc(axis=0)[:,A,B]`

Also, where I needed specific values, the original syntax changed from

```
df_options.loc[new, 'sim']
```

to

```
df_options.xs(new, level='idx')['sim'].values[0]
```

or

```
df_options.loc(axis=0)[new,:,:]['sim'].values[0]
```

("new" is the randomly chosen next index of df, and 'sim' is a column of pairwise similarity scores.)

As I hacked away trying to get this to work, I kept getting errors like `'...not hashable'` and `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'get_loc_level`

Which brings me to the question in the title: what am I doing wrong? More specifically:
1) does multiindex really have the potential to speed this process up like I think?,
2) if so, what are the correct idioms to use here (feels like I'm up a creek with .xs and .loc),
3) or should I use something else like raw numpy?

**EDIT** In the process of creating an example with code, I managed to get it working. I would say that I had to jump through some awkward hoops though, like `.values[0]` in `row.p2.values[0]` and `df.index[rand_pair][0][0]`.

In response to Jeff:
pandas 0.14.1

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 561567 entries, (0, 0, 003) to (561566, 26127, 011)
Data columns (total 14 columns):
p1              561567 non-null int64
smp1            561567 non-null object
rt1             561567 non-null float64
cas1            561567 non-null object
sim1            561567 non-null float64
p2              561567 non-null int64
smp2            561567 non-null object
rt2             561567 non-null float64
cas2            561567 non-null object
sim2            561567 non-null float64
nlsim1          561567 non-null float64
sum_spec_sq1    561567 non-null float64
sum_spec_sq2    561567 non-null float64
sum_s1s2        561567 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(8), int64(2), object(4)
```

Note: "p1", "smp2", and "nlsim1" correspond to "A" "B", and "sim" in my question above.
Enough data to walk a couple steps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({u'nlsim1': {174513: 0.8782, 270870: 0.9461, 478503: 0.8809},
 u'p1': {174513: 8655, 270870: 13307, 478503: 22276},
 u'p2': {174513: 13307, 270870: 22276, 478503: 2391},
 u'smp1': {174513: u'007', 270870: u'010', 478503: u'016'},
 u'smp2': {174513: u'010', 270870: u'016', 478503: u'002'}})
df.index = df.index.rename('idx')
df = df.set_index(['p1', 'smp2'], drop=False, append=True, verify_integrity=True)

def weighted_random_choice():
    options = df_options.index.tolist()
    tot = df_options.nlsim1.sum()
    options_weight = df_options.nlsim1 / tot
    return np.random.choice(options, p=list(options_weight))
```

Initiates the walk:

```
samples = set([c for a, b, c in df.index.values])
df_numbered = range(df.shape[0])
#rand_pair = random.sample(df_numbered, 1)
rand_pair = [0]
path = [df.index[rand_pair][0][0]]
```

The walk (iterate it):

```
row = df.loc[path[-1],:,:]
p = row.p2.values[0]
smp = row.smp2.values[0]
print p, smp
samples.discard(smp)
print sorted(list(samples))
pick_sample = random.sample(samples, 1)[0]
print pick_sample
df_options = df.xs((p, pick_sample), level=('p1', 'smp2'))
if df_options.shape[0] < 1:
    print "out of options, stop iterating"
    print "path=", path
else:
    print "# options: ", df_options.shape[0]
    new = weighted_random_choice()
    path.append(new)
    print path
    print "you should keep going"
```

output, 1st step:

```
13307 010
[u'002', u'016']
016
# options:  1
[174513, 270870]
you should keep going
```

2nd step:

```
22276 016
[u'002']
002
# options:  1
[174513, 270870, 478503]
you should keep going
```

3rd step errors as expected b/c it runs out of samples.

Comment: well, you should start by showing a complete copy/pastable example of your input and output, df.info() on your real dataset, and pandas version.

Comment: @Jeff I'm working on pastable code for you. My guess had been that I was doing something totally, obviously wrong, but your request for details gives me hope...

Comment: ok, now just need a sample of an input frame and the output you are expecting (should by copy/pastable and runable; just generate random data, but the index should be in-line with what you are doing). the df.info() gives an idea of your real data.

Comment: In the process of creating an example with code, I managed to get it working. I would say that I had to jump through some awkward hoops though, like `.values[0]` in `row.p2.values[0]` and `df.index[rand_pair][0][0]`.

Comment: Is there a way to have the 'idx' index and ('p1', 'smp2') index act independently of each other?

Comment: I am not clear what is your bottleneck. Can you give a simpler example of what you are doing, completely copy-pastable code. The code you pasted does not illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple fix was to use two copies of the data frame, the original and another one indexed by 'A' and 'B':

```
dfi = df.set_index(['A', 'B'])
```

By changing the "select specific A, B" paradigm from

```
df_options = df[(df.A == x) & (df.B == y)]
```

to

```
df_options = dfi.loc(axis=0)[x, y]
```

I was able to gain a 5x improvement in speed. It should scale better with the size of df.